# Why is there a NPE on a missing Java Permission? And how to find out which Permission?

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet, event-dispatch-thread

I have a Java Applet, that runs fine when `permission java.security.AllPermission;` is granted in the `java.policy` file.

But I really just want to set the one permission needed for my Application - so I deleted the line `permission java.security.AllPermission;` in the policy file, expecting an *Access Denied* Exception or something along those lines, but all I get is a NullPointerException at the following Code:

```
protected Object[] __ObjectArrayResult;

(...)

final Container c = (Container) container;

        InvocationWrapper.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                __ObjectArrayResult = c.getComponents();
            }
        });

        Object[] components = __ObjectArrayResult;

        Vector componentVector = Utils.convertArrayToVector(components);
```

What I am trying here, is to get all the Conponents of a AWT Container, but `c.getComponents();` returns Null, and the `Utils.convertArrayToVector(components);` throws the NPE.

So why does the getComponents method (if it needs some special Permission) not throw an exception and just return Null? I looked through the Documentation, but no case is mentioned, which would return Null.

---

The next thing I've tried is to Debug the Permissions. Using that approach, I found this: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html

Where it states that `-Djava.security.debug=access` could be used to see all the Results of `AccessController.checkPermission`

But running that just gave me the following:

```
access: access denied ("java.security.AllPermission" "<all permissions>" "<all actions>")
access: access denied ("java.security.AllPermission" "<all permissions>" "<all actions>")
access: access denied ("java.security.AllPermission" "<all permissions>" "<all actions>")
access: access denied ("java.security.AllPermission" "<all permissions>" "<all actions>")
access: access denied ("java.security.AllPermission" "<all permissions>" "<all actions>")
access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read")
access: access denied ("java.security.AllPermission" "<all permissions>" "<all actions>")
Exception in thread "Thread-19" access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
access: access allowed ("java.io.SerializablePermission" "enableSubstitution")
java.lang.NullPointerException: Utils::convertArrayToVector - Array is NULL!
```

I have no clue what to make of this. It says that `AllPermissions` is denied, does this mean that some Method Asks the `AccessController` for all the Permissions? or is it trying to get `"java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread"` by first trying to get the more general permission `allPermission`?

---

So to summarize: Why is `getComponents()` returning Null? Why does it not throw an Exception and tell me which Permission is needed? Why is `AllPermission` requested instead of a more specific permission?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your invocations of the EDT not to swallow exceptions:

```
    final Container c = (Container) container;
    final AtomicReference<Object[]> result = new AtomicReference<>();
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                result.set(c.getComponents());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Object[] components = result.get();
    Vector componentVector = Utils.convertArrayToVector(components);
```

You will now be able to *see* where your code fails missing a permission.

You also note that exchanging a value between Runnable and invoking thread is done safely using a *local* reference (result). Doing this through an instance member is extremely bad style, and outright broken if used in a context where more than one thread could execute the runnable concurrently.

Its also notable that Vector is almost *never* what you want to use (because Vector is synchronized). Switch to ArrayList when you don't need synchronized access (and you almost *never* need that).